# Java JComboBox Autocomplete

Tags: java, swing, drop-down-menu, autocomplete, jcombobox

I have an ArrayList of People - which is made up of a Name, email, and a few numbers (however they are all strings). I use this list to populate a JComboBox on my form.

What I want to implement is an auto-complete JComboBox, so, for example, when typing in Tim:

Press "T" -> It will drop-down display everything beginning with "T"

Press "i" -> It will drop-down display everything that begins with "Ti"

Press "m" -> It will drop down display everything that has "Tim" at the beginning.

I've tried a few ways - looked at things like SwingX, but it seems that servers are down and I can't access any documentation. I have tried creating my own algorithm, but it's getting quite complicated and i've been going down some dead ends. I was wondering if anyone knew of any good methods to achieve what I am trying?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was wondering if anyone knew of any good methods to achieve what I am trying?

Use any of the existing libraries that provide autocompletion. SwingX has indeed such a feature in the API, but others are available as well.

Take a look at [this article](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/07/19/adding-auto-completion-to-swing-comboboxes.html) which contains more information on autocompletion in Java and contains links to some 3th party libs which offer this functionality

Comment: Thanks - just did some more digging and found the downloads for SwingX. All installed now and working. Thank you!