# Java suggest autocomplete?

Tags: c#, java, swing

i'm developing an app in java, i have seen in c# the autocomplete suggest in windows forms and is exactly what i need. Is there any equivalent in java?
Is similar like this. 
[image: c# autocomplete suggest image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a autocompleting textbox in Java with a dropdown list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186955/create-a-autocompleting-textbox-in-java-with-a-dropdown-list) also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583344/java-jcombobox-autocomplete

Comment: oks. Where is the reference guide for windows form programming in c#?

Comment: I absolutely hate it when Google isn't working. Give it a few minutes, and maybe it will be back up and running soon.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to your questions is in this other Stack Overflow thread: [How could I implement autocompletion using Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485530/how-could-i-implement-autocompletion-using-swing)

Note, the one that's accepted as the answer didn't get as much votes as the one that says:

> You might want to try the free AutoComplete component over at SwingLabs.
>
> http://swinglabs.org
>
> There is an example how to implement this code at:
>
> http://javadesktop.org/swinglabs/build/weekly/latest/swingx-HEAD/javadoc/org/jdesktop/swingx/autocomplete/package-summary.html

Comment: Seriously? You're posting a link to the dup and copy/pasting one of the answers?

Comment: It answers his question doesn't it?